# Parsing addressComponents in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am unable to get full country name and state name on initialize and update on addressComponents. Though i am getting short names i would like to parse and retreive long_name of state and country.

JS

```
function updateControls(addressComponents) {

    $('#ustate').val(addressComponents.stateOrProvince);

    $('#ucountry').val(addressComponents.country);
}

$('#mapz').locationpicker({
    location: {
        latitude: 45.91886765642549,
        longitude: -77.57585875078735
    },
    radius: 300,

    inputBinding: {
        locationNameInput: $('#pac-input'),
    },
    enableAutocomplete: true,
    onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
        var addressComponents = $(this).locationpicker('map').location.addressComponents;
        updateControls(addressComponents);
    },
    oninitialized: function(component) {
        var addressComponents = $(component).locationpicker('map').location.addressComponents;
        updateControls(addressComponents);
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<div style="width: 900px !important; height:300px !important" id="mapz"></div>

<input  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Box" id="pac-input" class="text_field" type="text">

<input type="text" name="ucountry" id="ucountry"  size="45" value=""  class="text_field" />

<input type="text" name="ustate"  id="ustate" maxlength="75"  class="text_field" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the country from the below code:

```
function getCountry(addrComponents) {
        for (var i = 0; i < addrComponents.length; i++) {
            if (addrComponents[i].types[0] === "country") {
                console.log(addrComponents[i].long_name);
                return addrComponents[i].long_name;
            }
            if (addrComponents[i].types.length === 2) {
                if (addrComponents[i].types[0] === "political")
                {
                    console.log(addrComponents[i].long_name);
                    return addrComponents[i].long_name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For state use the below function:

```
function getState(addrComponents) {
            for (var i = 0; i < addrComponents.length; i++) {
                if (addrComponents[i].types[0] === "administrative_area_level_1")    {
                    console.log(addrComponents[i].long_name);
                    return addrComponents[i].long_name;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No bro , placed alert instead console.log & also tried to store long name in global variable still nothing can be retreived.  can u edit my code if possible

Comment: create a fiddle and i will see to it

Comment: i have created a fiddle but unable to display map. https://jsfiddle.net/kishorejv/md1L2285/1/#&togetherjs=Kcx0lHtCv7